# Vectorization of mulivariable gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I've been doing the homework 1 in Andrew Ng's machine learning course. But I'm stuck on my understanding of what he was talking about when vectorizing the multivariable gradient descent.

his equation is presented as follows:
theta := theta - alpha*f

f is supposed to be created by 1/m*sum(h(xi)-yi)*Xi where i is the index

now here is where I get confused, I know that h(xi)-y(i) can be rewritten as theta*xi where xi represents a row of feature elements (1xn) and theta represents a column (nx1) producing a scalar which I then subtract from an individual value of y, which I then multiply by Xi where Xi represents a column of 1 features values?

so that would give me mx1 vector? which then has to be subtracted from an nx1 vector?

is it that Xi represents a row of feature values? and if so how can I do this without indexing over all of these rows?

I'm specifically referring to this image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain it with the non-vectorized implementation

> so that would give me mx1 vector? which then has to be subtracted from
>   an nx1 vector?

yes it will give you *m x 1* vector, but instead to be subtracted from *n x 1* vector, it has to be subtracted from *m x 1* vector too. How?

> I know that h(xi)-y(i) can be rewritten as theta*xi where xi
>   represents a row of feature elements (1xn) and theta represents a
>   column (nx1) producing a scalar

you have answer it actually, theta * xi produce a scalar, so when you have *m* samples it will give you a *m x 1* vector. If you see carefully in the equation the scalar result from *h(xi) - y(i)* is multiplied with a scalar too which is *x0 from sample i* (x sup i sub 0) so it will give you a scalar result, or *m x 1* vector if you have m samples.